# Books for maths olympiad

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory, contest-math, book-recommendation

I want to prepare for the maths olympiad and I was wondering if you can recommend me some books about combinatorics, number theory and geometry at a beginner and intermediate level. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Olympiad_books

Comment: A great book to learn problem solving is 'Art and craft of problem solving' by Paul Zeitz.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solving strategy by Engel. Pretty advanced though

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a good Geometry book, you can check out Evan Chen's book, *Euclidean Geometry In Mathematical Olympiads.*  There are no prerequisites to the book; all you need to do is know how to read proofs.  A PDF of the book is $28:

http://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/euclidean-geometry-in-mathematical-olympiads

As a sample, here's a free PDF of chapter 2:

http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/ebooks/pdf/EGMO_chapter2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

An elementary intro to combinatorics, with exercises: 
[https://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Highschooler-Alexander-Sadovsky/dp/1453869670/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1469170334&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=sadovsky+discrete+math+for+highschooler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1453869670)

Instructional videos on combinatorics:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrfA8mKOIjI

Books specifically on contest problems:
[https://www.amazon.com/William-Lowell-Mathematical-Competition-1985-2000/dp/088385807X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1469170542&sr=1-1&keywords=putnam+problems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/088385807X)

[https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Olympiads-1993-1999-Circles-Library/dp/0821853635/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1469170403&sr=1-1&keywords=moscow+olympiad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821853635)

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite mathematical olympiad books is this one:
https://www.amazon.es/Mathematical-Olympiad-Challenges-Titu-Andreescu/dp/0817645284
by Andreescu and Gelca. It's more on the itermediate level. It is sort of a compilation on useful techniques with sample problems. I suggest you give it a go.