# Olympiad Books for Primary Students

Tags: geometry, logic, reference-request, contest-math

I am a teacher of gifted program in primary school and currently I am developing Olympiad Curriculum (topic-wise) for my students. I have those topics that could need some help in terms of questions:

- Number theory: common multiples, unit digit, divisibility and remainder
- Combinatorics: counting figures
- Geometry: area of polygons and circles
- Logical thinking: logical puzzles
- Arithmetic: solve complex arithmetical problems, number puzzles..

Can anyone suggest good books/e-books for me to add in question banks? Thank you!

Comment: What is *gifted* program?

Comment: In English, at least in the US, a person with extraordinary talent, particularly a child, is called "gifted." As in: God, or Odin, or the Flying Spaghetti Monster gave this person a gift at birth (rather than talent achieved through hard work.) @tatan Gifted programs are programs for gifted students.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867257/books-for-maths-olympiad?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

For olympiads

- Number Theory this is a must-**"Number Theory-Andrescu
  Titu"**-https://blngcc.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/andreescu-andrica-problems-on-number-theory.pdf
- And for Geometry this one-**"Coxeter-Geometry Revisited"**-http://www.aproged.pt/biblioteca/geometryrevisited_coxetergreitzer.pdf
- I have another good book,but I have no idea if it's available outside India.It covers all topics necessary for the Olympiads.It is-"**Challenge and thrill of pre-college mathematics** by V Krishnamurthy, C R Pranesachar,K.N. Ranganathan and B.J. Venkatachala"-https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Challenge_and_Thrill_of_Pre_College_Math.html?id=SnvBeodeTDcC
- This [link](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Olympiad_books) might also help.

All this books start from the most basic level and progresses till the most advanced concepts in a lucid way.If you want more advanced books,you may mention in the comments.

Comment: I think this could help everyone! Thanks for the post :) however, do you think this is the level the OP is looking for? Will primary school students be able to grasp this? I would really like to know what the OP had in mind (types of questions and difficulty) @Andrew Hoang

Comment: @JoshuaLochner This books start from quite basic level and if there's someone to explain you (a good teacher) this books are a real asset to you...btw,if you like my post,you can upvote it...;-)

Comment: Agreed ;) Upvote :D do you maybe have any other suggestions? I would love to read some of these. Also would it be possible to provide a "grade" or "year" for each book?

Comment: @JoshuaLochner Yeah...I hope you would love to read these....

Comment: @JoshuaLochner "Year" and "Grade" are relative terms...if you are interested you can read all the books today only....See this post-http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150242/teenager-solves-newton-dynamics-problem-where-is-the-paper ....If 16 year boy can solve 300 year old maths problem given by Newton,it proves that grade or year is not necessary to gain knowledge....

Comment: In my opinion, the contents in those links provided by tatan is not suitable for primary students (except for the "genius". This type I cannot handle xD ). But thank you anyway for supporting this topic tatan. @JoshuaLochner

Comment: @AndrewHoang These books are the ones I use myself for self study...I don't feel that they are for "the genius"...but they are for the "dedicated" ones....by the way,the students have you as a teacher...you can make their job easier....